# launching dask-cuda LocalCUDACluster within SLURMCluster

Tags: dask, slurm

I want to launch a cluster on Slurm. Whereas, on each node, a LocalCUDACluster should be launched to use the available GPUs on each node. My sample code looks as follows:

```
import dask
from dask.distributed import Client
from dask_jobqueue import SLURMCluster
from dask_cuda import LocalCUDACluster
import os

def test():
    #return(cuda.get_current_device().id)
    return([i.id for i in cuda.list_devices()])
    
def test_numba_cuda():
    cluster = LocalCUDACluster()
    client = Client(cluster)
    return(cluster.cuda_visible_devices)
    
queue = "gpus"  #  batch, gpus, develgpus, etc.
project = "deepacf"  # your project: zam, training19xx, etc.
port = 56755

cluster = SLURMCluster(
     n_workers=2,
     cores=1,
     processes=2,
     memory="5GB",
     shebang="#!/usr/bin/env bash",
     queue=queue,
     scheduler_options={"dashboard_address": ":"+str(port)},
     walltime="00:30:00",
     local_directory="/tmp",
     death_timeout="30m",
     log_directory=f'{os.environ["HOME"]}/dask_jobqueue_logs',
     interface="ib0",
     project=project,
     python="/p/home/jusers/elshambakey1/juwels/jupyter/kernels/dg_rr_analytics/bin/python",
     nanny=False,
     job_extra=['--gres gpu:4']
)

client=Client(cluster)
ts=[dask.delayed(test_numba_cuda)()]
res=client.compute(ts)
res[0].result()
```

I had to set `nanny=False` because, otherwise, I receive an error about daemonized tasks that cannot have children. Thus, I found a similar problem at https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/2142. So, I set `nanny=False`. It worked fine when `n_workers=1` and `processes=1`. But when I tried to set both `n_workers=2` and `processes=2`, it fails with the following error:
`distributed.dask_worker - ERROR - Failed to launch worker.  You cannot use the --no-nanny argument when n_workers > 1`

I wonder how to solve this problem.

Comment: the standard way to do this would be to configure your SLURM cluster to make use of the gpus. is this not an option for some reason?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Thanks for your comment, but I'm not sure I follow. Slurm is configured to access GPUs. But I need to write the whole code in Python without directly writting sbatch files.

Answer (score 0):

You can get over the error

```
distributed.dask_worker - ERROR - Failed to launch worker.  You cannot use the --no-nanny argument when n_workers > 1
```

just by using nanny and asking it not to use daemons for workers. Just add the following to the SLURMCluster builder call:

```
job_script_prologue=["export DASK_DISTRIBUTED__WORKER__DAEMON=False"],
nanny=True
```